# Is there inverse FFT algorithm for Fourier transform of a integer-valued random variable?

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, generating-functions, fourier-transform

In many applications, it is possible to derive an explicit expression for the
Fourier transform of a random variable $X$ 
$$\varphi (\theta ) = \sum\limits_{n =  0}^\infty  {{p_n}} {e^{in\theta }}$$
whose probability mass function is not readily available and has a complicated form. If an explicit expression for the Fourier transform of the random variable $X$ is available, then the numerical values of the (unknown)
probability mass function of $X$ can be calculated by appealing to the inverse Fast
Fourier Transform method from numerical analysis. The basic idea(algorithm) of inverse FFT is to break up a transform of length $N$ into two transforms of length $N/2$ using the identity
$$\sum\limits_{n = 0}^{N - 1} {{a_n}} {e^{ - 2\pi ink/N}} = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^{N/2 - 1} {{a_{2n}}} {e^{ - 2\pi i(2n)k/N}} + {e^{ - 2\pi ik/N}}\sum\limits_{n = 0}^{N/2 - 1} {{a_{2n + 1}}} {e^{ - 2\pi i(2n)k/N}}.$$
However, I want to derive an explicit expression for the
Fourier transform of a integer-valued random variable $X$ 
$$\varphi (\theta ) = \sum\limits_{n =  - \infty }^\infty  {{p_n}} {e^{in\theta }}$$
whose probability mass function is not readily available and has a complicated form.

It is seen that Matlab or R only provide the FFT command of non-negative integer-valued case for computing FFT. Is there a similar FFT algorithm for integer-valued situation?